# UINavigationController not working as intended (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

The main view of my app don't have a `UINavigationController` but when a button is tapped it goes to a view to create an event. This CreateEvent view does have a `UINavigationController` to move though the differents views needed to create the new event. The `UINavigationController` is displayed but can't set a title or add any navigation buttons, looking at the code can you find out why? Thanks

`CreateNewEventViewController.h`

```
@interface CreateNewEventViewController : UIViewController {

    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    NewEventTableViewController *tableViewController;
}
```

`CreateNewEventViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    tableViewController = [[NewEventTableViewController alloc] init];
    tableViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(tableViewController.view.frame.size.width/2,
                                                  tableViewController.view.frame.size.height/2 + 44);
    [self.view addSubview:tableViewController.view];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    //without this instruction, the tableView appears blocked
    navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    //title appears empty and buttons don't appear
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Create event";

    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

}
```

`NewEventTableViewController.h`

```
@interface NewEventTableViewController : UITableViewController {

}
```

PS: I forgot to tell that I don't have any `.xib` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the table view to appear within the navigation controller, you need to do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    tableViewController = [[NewEventTableViewController alloc] init];
    tableViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(tableViewController.view.frame.size.width/2,
                                                  tableViewController.view.frame.size.height/2 + 44);

 // remove this:   [self.view addSubview:tableViewController.view];

    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController]; // <-- do this instead
    //without this instruction, the tableView appears blocked
    navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460); // <-- nav controller should fill the screen
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    //title appears empty and buttons don't appear
    tableViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Create event"; // <-- something like this

    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

}
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked finally, I really should take a deeper view on UINavigationController topic. Just comment that setting the title from tableViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Create event"; didn't work but it did from viewDidLoad in NewEventTableViewController.m